# derivative with respect to a vector

Tags: fractions, vector

```
\[
\frac{\partial f}
     {\partial
\left(
\begin{array}{l}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{array}
\right)
}
\]
```

gives

[image]

Can you help me to improve this by reducing the size of the denominator?

Comment: write it as {x,y,z}^T where T is transpose (if it must be a column vector, else leave it as row vector)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `psmallmatrix` environment from »[mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)« could come in handy here. Partial derivatives are easier to typeset with the help of the »[physics](http://ctan.org/pkg/physics)« package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
  \[
    \pdv{f}{%
      \begin{psmallmatrix}
        x \\ y \\ z
      \end{psmallmatrix}
    }
  \]
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I've upvoted all previous solutions, and accepted yours for the psmallmatrix environment! Thx

Comment: When using only `amsmath` and not `mathtools` the same can be achieved with `\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{smallmatrix}\right)`.

Comment: @canaaerus: But `psmallmatrix` is easier due to less typing. And »[mathtools](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)« offers many other enhancements to »[amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)«.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: That is true. Although to have to type less, a special macro or an editor short-cut is superior to both. My comment was only meant for people who are not able or do not want to use `mathtools`.

Comment: @canaaerus: I can't see why a short-cut or a special macro should be superior over a sophisticated package. And furthermore I don't see reasons why one wouldn't want or be able to use that package.

Answer (score 7):

To *really* economize on vertical space, you could typeset the denominator term as a row vector -- and apply a transpose symbol to indicate that the result of the operation should be a column vector. Two possible ways to represent this approach are, the second possibility is based on a suggestion by @percusse.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \frac{\partial f}{\bigl( \partial (\,x \  y \  z\,) \bigr)'}
  \quad
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bigl( (\,x \  y \  z\,)' \bigr)}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the transpose should be in and the partial should be out of the outer brackets.

Comment: @percusse - Thanks, I've incorporated your comment by showing both possible solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\partial f}
     {\partial
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\[-4pt]
y \\[-3pt]
z
\end{pmatrix}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution with [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) and [`nccmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccmath) so as to ensure right-aligned matrices and medium size matrices:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
\[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
  x\\ y\\ z
\end{pmatrix*}}
\qquad
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial\begin{medsize}\begin{pmatrix*}[r]
  x\\ y\\ z
\end{pmatrix*}\end{medsize}}
\qquad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\begin{psmallmatrix*}[r]
  x\\ y\\ z
\end{psmallmatrix*}}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\PartDiff[4]{%
  \frac{\partial #1}{\partial \mkern-4mu
  \begingroup
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.7}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      #2\\  #3\\  #4
    \end{pmatrix}
  \endgroup
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \PartDiff{f}{x}{y}{z}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that the distance between the rows is adjusted by `\arraystretch`.

If you enclose the `\begingroup`/`\endgroup` construction in curly braces (`{}`), you also reduce the spacing around the vector:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\PartDiff[4]{%
  \frac{\partial #1}{\partial{
  \begingroup
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.7}
    \begin{pmatrix}
      #2\\  #3\\  #4
    \end{pmatrix}
  \endgroup
  }}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \PartDiff{f}{x}{y}{z}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit out-of-the-box, but why not use

```
\nabla f ?
```

Or use

```
\partial_{\vec r} f
```

with

```
\vec r := \left( \begin{array}{l} x\\ y\\ z \end{array} \right) ?
```